# Ordinal JSF-paging with breadcrumbs composite components

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I want to split a big form into several composite components (since I reuse the CCs). One major page (business process page) must allow a user to navigate across 4 CCs. Not necessarily in a sequential order. The user may use the breadcrumbs of the major page to jumb from 1 to 4 - or - use the arrows to navigate sequentially back and forth.

Requirements:

1. All navigation items (arrows and breadcrumbs) must be placed on the major page.
2. The major page must never be reloaded. The CCs only.
3. The user is able to leave the site temporarily without losing the data provided (since there are many fields on these pages).

What's the top-notch approach?

Shell I create @SessionScoped manged bean (controller), which renders CCs instance within a h:panelGroup?

```
<h:panelGroup id="businessProcessForm" layout="block">
    <my:composite rendered="#{controllerBean.navigateToCC}" />
</h:panelGroup>

<h:commandButton value="load previous CC" action="#{controllerBean.setNextCC('CC1')}">
    <f:ajax render="businessProcessForm" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton value="load next CC" action="#{controllerBean.setNextCC('CC3')}">
    <f:ajax render="businessProcessForm" />
</h:commandButton>
```

How do I set the links for the breadcrumbs (they must be created according to the number of CCs)?
How do I set the previous/next links?
How do I populate the h:panelGroup by the arrows or breadcrumbs?

Any solid answers (including Richfaces)?

Answer (score 0):

Providing an answer very late. If you have better alternative of implementing Breadcrumbs in JSF and RichFaces please do let me know.

RichFaces itself does not provide any kind of BreadCrumbs components like the one provided by Trinidad from MyFaces. 
An alternative to create a breadcrumb like structure would be to dynamically add images and links in  and bind this grid to the backing bean. As and when user navigate from one page to another particularly after doing certain kind of operation, a new  component and a corresponding image can be added into this grid and then grid can be rerendered